# Selecting factor for labels (ggplot2, directlabels)

Tags: r, ggplot2, direct-labels

I'd like to use the package directlabels to label my plot. However, I'd like the label to be the ID of each point. Is there really no way to select which factor to label or did I miss that?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)
df <- structure(
    list(id = 1:10,
         group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
         .Label = c("A", "B"),
         class = "factor"),
         value1 = c(4, 1, 6, 2, 5, 7, 3, 2, 5, 8),
         value2 = c(6, 2, 6, 2, 8, 9, 7, 5, 2, 6)
         ),
.Names = c("id", "group", "value1", "value2"),
row.names = c(NA, -10L),
class = "data.frame")

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=value1, y=value2)) + geom_point(aes(colour=group))
direct.label(p1)
```

[image]

Comment: Why not just use `geom_text`?

Comment: `direct.label` is used as an alternative of the legends (i.e. it is used to show the groups in your graph) not as a way to add labels on each point. For point labels use `geom_text` as Jaap mentions in his comment.

Comment: @Jaap because my actual plot consists of around 200 points and with `geom_text` a lot of the labels are overlapped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inspecting [the code of `direct.label.ggplot()`](https://github.com/cran/directlabels/blob/921faeca656f6e7ab71ef9ac2f3c3feb97bbcb35/R/ggplot2.R#L141-142) shows that `geom_dl()` is called in the end. This function expects an aesthetic mapping and a positioning method. The positioning method used [by default](https://github.com/cran/directlabels/blob/921faeca656f6e7ab71ef9ac2f3c3feb97bbcb35/R/ggplot2.R#L135) is the return value of `default.picker("ggplot")`, which uses call stack examination and in your case is equivalent to calling `defaultpf.ggplot("point",,,)`. The following works for me:

```
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=value1, y=value2)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour=group)) +
  geom_dl(aes(label = id), method = defaultpf.ggplot("point",,,))
p1
```

[image: Plot]

(Note that you don't need to call `direct.label()` anymore.)

The documentation of the `directlabels` package is indeed a bit scarce.

Comment: fantastic, thank you! I just have one more problem.. In my actual plot there a LOT of points very close together and some of the labels are now far away from the points, is there a way to limit the distance between point and label?

Comment: Could you perhaps post an example in a separate question?

Comment: From my experience with `direct labels`, in general it works fairly well to avoid overlapping labels; except, of course, in the case where you have many many points that are close together. There are a few different spacing options you can select within `direct labels`, but I haven't found a solution to the issue you are posing (i.e., the labels always seem to be far away from the points, if they aren't overlapping). It's the issue of using a generalized function for a specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a custom position method, like so:

```
label_all <- list( dl.trans(x = x + 0.5, y = y + 0.5), # shift every point up and right
                   gapply.fun(d) ) # include all points
direct.label(p1, method = label_all)
```

[image]

For another example, see [the documentation](http://directlabels.r-forge.r-project.org/examples.html), under "Specifying the positioning method as a list".

Comment: From my understanding, OP wants to take advantage of the positioning method provided by `directlabels`. Your answer simply uses a default positioning method, which in my opinion also could have been achieved via `geom_text` as suggested in the comments.

Comment: Seems you're right, and a nice answer you gave indeed. I might make use of that some day as well.