# Labelling points with ggplot2 and directlabels

Tags: r, ggplot2, direct-labels

This is a follow-up to my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32862981/3283824). While the answer by krlmlr somehow helps to solve my problem, one issue remains - the labels are moved far away from the points such that it gets impossible to see which label corresponds to which point. Does anyone know how to fix this?

## Test data

```
test <- structure(list(ID = c(183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 
    191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 202, 203, 204
    ), group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("a", 
    "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", 
    "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"), class = "factor"), 
        x = c(27.4921834914348, 25.9627681619548, 30.4138361188149, 
        29.7795838507818, 32.33351964819, 31.9669266268744, 35.4433172141507, 
        37.8161067968601, 43.1590654001956, 44.2747819266045, 46.3829222044342, 
        42.2074195880057, 45.4532493462957, 48.393281430824, 51.7145681408198, 
        51.4911582677409, 51.9582538485293, 51.3328966791848, 36.4638478746633, 
        36.6113033420253, 39.3476493044906), y = c(-40.6667236544384, 
        -39.2640436250506, -40.6403794753022, -40.907139119954, -39.9691483441288, 
        -39.7485517513382, -38.595662907188, -38.2106224386729, -37.6418188651769, 
        -32.7096448721895, -34.1161006958616, -32.2821584775403, 
        -30.8436917254975, -30.3865899667262, -30.3910690518699, 
        -26.1013343566452, -23.8437232732877, -21.5548787351057, 
        5.50922747751602, 5.64434551903915, 5.01263995541617)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -21L), .Names = c("ID", "group", "x", "y"), class = "data.frame")

library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)
```

## Plot using `geom_text` - problem: labels overlap

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
geom_point(aes(colour=group)) + 
geom_text(aes(label=ID), show_guide=F)
```

[image]

## Plot as suggested by [krlmlr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32862981/3283824) - problem: labels are far away from points

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
geom_point(aes(colour=group)) + 
geom_dl(aes(label = ID), method = defaultpf.ggplot("point",,,))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to avoid overlapping (to some degree at least) would be to offset each label by an amount which is determined by the closest point to it. So for example if a point's closest neighbouring point is directly to the right of it, its label would be placed to the left, etc.

```
# centre and normalise variables
test$yy  <- (test$y - min(test$y)) / (max(test$y) - min(test$y))
test$xx  <- (test$x - min(test$x)) / (max(test$x) - min(test$x))
test$angle <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(test)) {
    dx <- test[-i, ]$xx - test[i, ]$xx
    dy <- test[-i, ]$yy - test[i, ]$yy
    j <- which.min(dx ^ 2 + dy ^ 2)
    theta <- atan2((test[-i, ]$yy[j] - test[i, ]$yy), (test[-i, ]$xx[j] - test[i, ]$xx))
    test[i, ]$angle <- theta + pi
}
sc <- 0.5
test$nudge.x <- cos(test$angle) * sc
test$nudge.y <- sin(test$angle) * sc

ggplot(test, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
    geom_point(aes(colour=group)) + 
    geom_text(aes(x = x + nudge.x, y = y + nudge.y, label = ID), size = 3, show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

You can try playing around with the scaling parameter `sc` (the larger it is, the further away the labels will be from the points) to avoid overlapping labels. (I guess it may happen that not the same `sc` can be applied to all points to avoid overlaps - in that case you need to change the scaling parameter for each point maybe by defining `sc` using `dx` and `dy`).

Answer (score 7):

It could be that `ggrepel` is better suited to the labelling of points in a scatterplot.

```
library(ggplot2)  # ggrepel requires ggpot2 v2.0.0
library(ggrepel)

ggplot(test, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 


geom_text_repel(aes(label = ID, color = group),  show.legend = FALSE,
                     box.padding = unit(0.45, "lines")) +

geom_point(aes(colour=group))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Maybe `hjust` and `vjust` is what you are looking for?

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour=group)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=ID), show_guide=F, hjust = 1.2, vjust = 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: My actual plots consist of 100-200 points, it's virtually impossible to find one value for hjust/vjust that avoids any overlapping, thus my need for a more "dynamic" way.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this just by adjusting the jittering parameter -- `... position = position_jitter...`. You may have to play around with it a tad since you've only given us 10% of your data:

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour=group), position= position_jitter(width= 1.5, height= 1)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=ID), show_guide=F, hjust = 1.2, vjust = -.5,
            position= position_jitter(width= 1.5, height= 1))
```

[image]